# Unable to bind views

Tags: java, android

These are the extracts of my classes

```
public class CommentsActivity extends BaseDrawerActivity implements SendCommentButton.OnSendClickListener {`
@Bind(R.id.btnSendComment)
SendCommentButton btnSendComment;
    private void setupComments() {
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    rvComments.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    rvComments.setHasFixedSize(true);
```

Below is the BaseDrawerActivity

```
public class BaseDrawerActivity extends BaseActivity {
```

Below is the BaseActivity extract

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
```

Below is the SendCommentButton class

```
public class SendCommentButton extends ViewAnimator implements View.OnClickListener {
```

When i run the the app starts well and when i want to display the sendcomment button, the app crashes.
This is what i get

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton cannot be cast to com.example.alsongdunstan.thefaithapp.ui.view.SendCommentButton
```

Am really not sure where the problem is because i did everything well
And by the way this is the layout for the recyclerview

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rvComments"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scrollbars="none" />
```

Thanks very much for the help

Comment: There's really not enough information here, but are you sure you didn't specify a regular `<Button>` in your layout, instead of a `<com.example.alsongdunstan.thefaithapp.ui.view.SendCommentButton>`?

Comment: Are you used any RadioButton anywhere in your layout?

Comment: @MikeM. I kind of used a regular button, thanks for that